# How can I redirect the output of a console application that creates its own child and redirects its child's output?

Tags: perl, winapi

I am using Perl to execute [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) and capture the output from the console. What seems odd to me is that when I execute the command with backticks, it correctly captures output every time.

For example, this Perl script **works**, and I've used this for many years on many different configurations:

```
use strict;
my @out;
@out = `psexec \\\\192.168.1.105 -u admin -p pass netstat -a`;

print @out;
```

This Perl script fails, and seems to reliably cause psexesvc to hang on the remote system:

```
use IPC::Open2;

my($chld_out, $chld_in, $pid);
$pid = open2($chld_out, $chld_in, 'psexec \\\\192.168.1.105 -u admin -p pass netstat -a');

waitpid( $pid, 0 );
my $child_exit_status = $? >> 8;
my $answer = <$chld_out>;

print "\n\n answer: $answer";
```

What is so strange to me is that backticks seem to never have any problem. Everything else does, including [examples in C++ from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

My suspicion is that the problem with IPC::Open2 and the example in C++ (linked above) is related to the fact that I'm redirecting STDIN and STDOUT from the command shell (cmd.exe), and the child process (psexec) does the same thing when communicating with my remote system.

Also, where in the perldocs can I find detailed information on how backticks work? I'm most interested in their "internals" on Windows.

Or, where in the Perl source can I review the inner workings of backticks (that may be biting off more than I can chew, but it's worth a shot at this point).

**UPDATE**:
Following Andy's suggestion, I found this works:

```
use IPC::Open2;

my($chld_out, $chld_in, $pid);
$pid = open2($chld_out, $chld_in, 'psexec \\\\192.168.1.105 -u admin -p pass netstat -a');

my @answer = <$chld_out>;
print "\n\n answer: @answer";

waitpid( $pid, 0 );
my $child_exit_status = $? >> 8;
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the output (`my $answer = <$chld_out>`) before calling `waitpid`?

Comment: Whoa, that makes it work. I have no idea why though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know very little about how this works on windows, so maybe somebody can provide a more specific answer, but when piping between processes in perl, you need to be careful to avoid undesired blocking and deadlocks. There is some discussion of various problem scenarios in [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html).

In your example, the immediate call to `waitpid` causes problems. One possibility is that the child cannot exit until something reads the output, so everything hangs since the parent is not going to read the output. Another possibility is that part of the data stream is shut down as part of the `waitpid` call, and this causes a problem with the remote process.

In any case, it would be better to read the output from the child process before calling `waitpid`.